# Counting values for multiple distinct rows in a SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm very new to SQL so please pardon my lack of knowledge. I'm also doing this for a class so please don't just give me the answer, I'd like to learn.

I have 3 tables of which are Contracts, PaymentTypes, InsuranceCompanies. I'm trying to join them and then display the number of contracts whose payment method is insurance, broken out by Insurance Company. I have done so, but it is not counting the amount of contracts per insurance company. It is instead counting how many InsuranceID's that are using Insurance and placing that into each Insurance Company count. Here is what I have for the SQL Query:

```
Select Distinct InsuranceCompanies.InsuranceCompany, Count (Contracts.InsuranceID)  as 'Number of contracts'
from  Contracts, PaymentTypes, InsuranceCompanies 
where (Contracts.PaymentTypeID = 3) AND (PaymentTypes.PaymentTypeID = 3) AND (Contracts.PaymentTypeID = PaymentTypes.PaymentTypeID) 
Group by InsuranceCompanies.InsuranceCompany
```

Here is what it outputs:

```
All Insurance       273
Best Insurance      273
Friendly Insurance  273
Insurance One       273
Safety Insurance    273
```

So my question is how can I have it count individual Insurance Companies then display it accordingly?

I took the answer given to me, applied all variables needed, and it functions perfectly! Here is the final working Query:

```
Select i.InsuranceCompany, Count(c.InsuranceID) as 'Number of contracts'
from  Contracts c
join paymenttypes p on p.PaymentTypeID = c.PaymentTypeID
join insurancecompanies i on i.InsuranceID = c.InsuranceID
where c.PaymentTypeID = 3 AND p.PaymentTypeID = 3
Group by i.InsuranceCompany
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot join conditions.

Comment: Bad habits to kick (https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins): using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 20 years ago) and its use is discouraged as @marc_s once responded to one of my answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look something like this, but as I'm missing parts of your structure I cannot fill in the part after `on`

```
Select i.InsuranceCompany, Count(c.InsuranceID) as 'Number of contracts'
from  Contracts c
join paymenttypes p on p.PaymentTypeID = c.PaymentTypeID
join insurancecompanies i on i.InsuranceID = c.InsuranceID
where c.PaymentTypeID = 3 AND p.PaymentTypeID = 3
Group by i.InsuranceCompany
```

so [read](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) about table join

Comment: I added the information and it works perfectly. I had some confusion on joins in the first place, but your answer really helped. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, great catch on moving the where behind the joins